# Equivalence relation and bijection

Tags: complex-numbers, equivalence-relations, quotient-set

I am completely stuck with this exercise.

We have an equivalence relation $\mathcal R$ of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such as : 
$\ x \mathcal{R} y \iff x - y \in \mathbb{Z} $

The question I am asked is to prove that  the quotient set $E/\mathcal{R}$ is a bijection with the set $\mathbb{U}$ of all complex numbers of modulus 1.

In such exercise, I usually start by writing the relationship as a function, which then helps me to prove the bijection.
But here, I can't even write the function, let alone understanding how to represent complex numbers of modulus 1...

Many thanks for any tips!

Comment: What is $E$, and how do complex numbers enter?

Comment: For any pair $x,y$ of real numbers, of course $x-y$ is again a real number, that is $x\mathcal Ry$. The equivalence relation that you describe is just trivial. The quotient set $E/\mathcal R$ is a singleton.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Good question :D

Comment: @Suzet Sorry, there was a typo. It s not x-y is a real, but x-y is an integer

Comment: Now it makes more sense =) So basically, the equivalence relation $\mathcal R$ makes us think of the real numbers « up to an integer ». The question you are asked is : how can we describe the unit circle in terms of real numbers up to integers ? There is a standard way to do so, which you may know already... !

Comment: Thanks @Suzet A standard way, well looks like trigonometry but I can't figure out what way to use.

Comment: Complex modulus 1 means on the unit circle. But how to translate and how to link this back to x-y in Z, I can't see

Comment: The natural geometric parameter for the unit circle would be the angle of the point you're considering (say, with respect to the $x$-axis for instance). An angle, up to a scaling, really is just a real number up to an integer... ! A concrete way to put this is via the function $f(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$ as Zeekless wrote in their answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function $
f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{U} : x \mapsto e^{2\pi i x}
$
induces the bijection between $\mathbb{R}/\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathbb{U}$.

Comment: Thanks both Suzet and Zeekless